# Multiorg using a Corporate License

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

My client purchased a **Corporate** licence.
I planned to ask him to purchase a second BU so that I can have these setting:

1. 1 service cloud org (production) -> MC Account [trackingProd->apiuserProd]
2. 1 service cloud org (Test) -> BU Test (under the same MC Account) [trackingTest->apiuserTest]

Some months ago for another client, We already proposed to purchase a new BU but I am not sure if that time, the licence was an **Enterprise**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-org does not depend on the type of license in Marketing Cloud:

[image]
As you can see above, all available editions support Marketing Cloud Connect.

If your client's edition only supports a single Business Unit, he can easily reach out to the Account Executive to purchase an additional business unit, without changing the edition.